# Intersection of nested closed intervals is not empty

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I am having a little bit of trouble with this problem, and I am not exactly sure where to start. Here is the problem:

> Suppose we are given the real numbers $X_n$ and $Y_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $X_n \leq X_{n + 1}$ and $Y_n \geq Y_{n + 1}$ for all $n$. If $C_n$ is the interval $[X_n, Y_n]$, show that $\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} C_n \neq \emptyset$

I started the solution by saying that given $C_n = [X_n, Y_n]$, we can say that
\begin{equation*}
\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} C_n = \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} [X_n, Y_n] = [X_1, Y_1] \cap [X_2, Y_2] \cap \cdots \cap [X_n, Y_n] \cap \cdots
\end{equation*}
From here, I am not exactly sure how to proceed to show that this intersection is an empty set. Some assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. Take all $X_n=1$ and all $Y_n=2$, then the intersection is $[1,2]$.

Comment: @Joe my bad, i made a typo error.

Comment: Do you also have $X_n \le Y_n$?

Comment: @Joe it wasn't stated in the question so I am not exactly sure. I guess it is to be assumed that $X_n \leq Y_n$ because we are showing the intersection of the interval $[X_n, Y_n]$

Comment: I would suggest starting by showing that the set of all  $X_n$ are bounded above and the set of all $Y_n$ are bounded below.

Comment: Your title says "is the empty set", as does your second to last sentence. But the problem says "$\ne \emptyset$" which means is **not** the empty set.

Comment: @Lee, the OP originally had that typo in the post also, but edited it. I just edited the title to match.

Comment: Does  [Is this a sufficient proof for the nested interval theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233903/is-this-a-sufficient-proof-for-the-nested-interval-theorem)  answer your question?This is the nested interval theorem, so I can get you better duplicates if this one doesn't work.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, thank you very much! this was a very resourceful link that you provided!

Comment: @maraik2002 Hey, good to know I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way would be to show that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}X_n \in \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}C_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Exercise. If $\emptyset\ne  A\subset\Bbb R$ and if $B$ is a non-empty set of upper bounds for $A$ then  $glb(B)$ is an upper bound for $A.$ Hence $lub(A)\le glb (B).$

With $A=\{X_n: n\in\Bbb N\}$ and $B=\{Y_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$ we have $X=lub (A)\le glb(B)=Y.$

For all $n$ we have $X_n\le X\le Y\le Y_n$. So for all $n$ we have $\emptyset\ne [X,Y]\subseteq [X_n,Y_n].$